# Prove by induction that $x^n$ can be calculated with at most $\log_2(n+1)$ multiplications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

**Basis.** When $n=0$, no multiplication is done to compute $x^{0}=1$. Since $\log_{2}(1)=0$, the base case holds.

**Step.** Suppose the claim holds for some $k \geq 0$. To show that $x^{k+1}$ can be computed with at most $\log_{2}(k+2)$ multiplications, notice that $x^{k+1} = x^{k}x$. We perform no multiplications to compute $x$, and the induction hypothesis guarantees we need no more than $\log_{2}(k+1)$ multiplications to compute $x^{k}$. Finally, we multiply $x^{k}$ with $x$. Thus, $x^{k+1}$ can be computed with at most
$$
\log_{2}(k+1) + 1 = \log_{2}(k+1) + \log_{2}(2) = \log_{2}(2(k+1)) = \log_{2}(k+k+2)
$$
multiplications.

How do I finish this proof? Am I not seeing some logarithm property?

Comment: You can’t do it just by multiplying by $x$ $k-1$ times, which is the algorithm your attempt is suggesting. I’m not sure you can do it in $\log_2(n+1)$ multiplications, but you can do it in $2\log_{2}(n+1)$ multiplications. See “exponentiation by squaring.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: For the original assertion, it seems that a counter example is $n = 6$, since $\log_2(7) < 3.$  I don't see how you can compute $x^6$ in only two multiplications.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you are right. Assuming the claim holds for every natural up to $k-1$, the inductive step is divided in two cases: $k$ even or odd. If even, $x^{k} = (x^{k/2})^2$, which requires at most $\log_{2}(k/2)+1 = \log_{2}(k) \leq \log_{2}(k+1)$ multiplications. But the odd case doesn't seem to work out: for $x^{k} = x(x^{(k-1)/2})^{2}$, we need at most $\log_{2}((k-1)/2)+2 = \log_{2}(k-1)+1 = \log_{2}(2(k-1))$.... Did I miss something?

Comment: Yeah, the worst cases are $n=2^m-1$ which requires $2(m-1)$ multiplications, and $\log_2(n+1)=m$

Comment: Just do a Division after  calculating $x^{n+1}$ for mersennes ...